# Jquery getting class from a custom attribute in a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if an attribute has a certain class on it:

```
$('span[last="lastWord"')
```

The above is what I have now. I want to check the span class with that attribute for its classes attribute... Basically what I'd like is a jQuery function to check that span class for a certain class. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: `$('span').hasClass('.classname')` try this

Comment: don't require dot before class name. e.g `$('span').hasClass('classname')`

Comment: `hasClass` is what you can look for

Comment: hasClass is perfect it made everything even easier! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As **@Pekka** points out in the comments, jQuery already has a method [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) that allows you to do this:

```
$('span').hasClass('yourClass');
```

Otherwise, you can do it in plain JS like:

```
// assuming you already have a reference to your element
function hasClass(elem, myClass) {
    return elem.classList.indexOf(myClass) !== -1;
}
```